# dopetrope left menu randomly disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the Dopetrope meanu form html5up.net:
http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/dopetrope/left-sidebar.html

This template is simply great but I am having an issue with the left hand menu when in mobile view.  When you click the famous burger icon (no matter which page) the menu slides in as expected and it works some of the time but not everytime.  It is not something I have added as it does it on the official demo site (above) too.

Go to the above URL and without clicking navigation links, just scroll the page up and down a few times, then click the burger icon.  Keep doing this a few times and you will find that on some occasions the left hand links and icon toggle disappears (just leaving the dark background).  But if you do see the burger icon, you can click it again and the menu will show again.

This only happens on mobile (android samsung S4 mini - happens pretty much 100% of the time).  Iphone 6 - happens say 40/60.

Could anyone help with providing a fix for this?  Or perhaps point me to the code that calls the menu to see if I can override a setting such as z-index or call the function twice?

Many thanks for anyone who can help.